# Proving that every odd non-prime number can be factorized with factors greater than 1.

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $n$ is not prime **but it is an odd number bigger than 1**, then the equation $(x+y)(x-y) = n$ has more than one solution. $x$ and $y$ can also not be negative.

I've substituted $n$ with $ab$
$$(x+y)(x-y) = ab$$

One obvious solution to this is if $$(x-y) = 1$$ $$(x+y) = ab$$
I've found that this works for all odd numbers.

Another solution is $$(x+y) = a$$ $$(x-y) = b$$

$$x = \frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$y = \frac{a-b}{2}$$

Since $ab$ is odd $a$ and $b$ must be odd separately and from that follows that both $x$ and $y$ are whole numbers. $y$ wont be negative since you can always choose the greater factor to be $a$.

So in essence, give me any $ab$ and I can give you an $x$ and a $y$ that satisfies the equation above. **However** I cannot prove that the first and second solutions are separate. How do I go about this? Am I even on the right track? Is there another way to prove it?

Comment: Not following.  The header and the text seem unrelated.  We have $15=15\times 1$ and $15=3\times 5$.  Is that what you mean by "more than one solution"?  But the header demands that the factors exceed $1$.

Comment: You've almost got it. The two solutions must be different since the value of $x-y$ is different for each. Now you can post the answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Your solutions are different if $$x_1 \neq x_2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{ab+1}{2} \neq \frac{a+b}{2} \Leftrightarrow ab + 1 \neq a+b\Leftrightarrow a(b-1)-(b-1) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow(a-1)(b-1)\neq 0.  $$

This is true because $n$ is not a prime number, you can always find $a,b>1$ such that $n = ab.$

Answer (score 1):

Choose $a, b $ both different from 1. If the two solutions would coincide you would have

$$ 1= x-y = \frac{a+b}{2} - \frac{a-b}{2} = b.$$

This is a contradiction.